# How to determine status of convergence of optimization in openMDAO?

Tags: openmdao

When calling top.run() in openMDAO, how could one determine if the optimization converged or not without looking at the printed output?

I would expect a flag with the convergence status which has different values depending on the cause of non-convergence. Is there anyway to retrieve such a flag in openMDAO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solvers return, from their `solve` method, a three tuple with the first item being a convergence flag.

Drivers are a bit trickier, because some optimizers don't give explicit feedback on their exit status. So there isn't a consistent way to deal with it.